# LC filter - how to deal with additional inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter

In the circuit below we have a positive potential VDD=3.3V and ground potential VSS=0V which are supplying the digital part of an integrated circuit. Digital part of circuit is operating at frequency f=12MHz and can therefore cause some disturbances. Same integrated circuit also has analog part which needs more stable potentials VDDA=3.3V and VSSA=0V derived from previously mentioned potentials by using LC filters.

But this are not ordinary filters because there are always 3 electronic elements added. I haven't found any calculus for example like this that would show, how to derive size of L2 and L3. Does anyone have idea how to derive the equation for L2 and L3 or could at least recommend a good book on the subject?

I tried simulating it with some random values for L2, L3 & L1, but it won't kill the 12MHz frequency entirely so I am lost without theory. I don't know if this is even the response I need to look for... 
[image]

---

After applying some changes like @The Photon suggested in the comments I really get better response and frequency is almost flattened out entirely. Not quite there yet, but it is better now. But it looks like it keeps on ringing...

[image]

---

Here is the clocking of my integrated circuit as user @analogsystemsrf requested in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have built yourself an inverted Pi filter. Why not a standard CLC if you have voltage stiff sources and loads?

Comment: Try reducing L3. If you are modeling a multilayer board with anything approximating a ground plane, 100 nH is a really big number for that parasitic.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331770/2451

Comment: @The Photon Hey I did decrease the L3 value and now I got better response. It **almost** flattens out the frequency (take a look at ma updated question)! Not quite there yet...

Comment: @71GA  you need a more accurate model for perfect critically damped solution.  Which IC? what stripline? what load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some dampening. Use Rdampen = sqrt(L/C).

For 0.1uf and 0.1uH, R = sqrt(1/1) = 1 OHM. Add 1 OHM in each ringing path.

Or place that 1 Ohm in parallel with each inductor.

The formula sqrt(L/C) produces a couple dB overshoot in a frequency response.

Here is a PI filter: 100nH from digital-section (10cm wire) into the PI 
of 10uF as Cpi1, into series R+L, into Cpi2 of 1uF. This provides 40+db filtering.

[image]

The series Resistor is crucial. Otherwise, lots of ringing as you see in your own simulations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsPZUw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What value should I use for L? I am asking because I have two inductors in each filter. Should I just sum their values?

Comment: How sensitive is the "analog" part of your system? How many bits?  What generates the 12MHz digital ringing?

Comment: My analog circuit is in fact 12-bit ADC. Please take a look at my updated question to see the clocking for my integrated circuit which is in fact a microcontroller (LPC4088) with an internal 12MHz oscilator that is directly powering the PLL's. Default clock for all the peripherals is 3MHz.

Comment: Lotta sensitive circuits there. I've edited my answer, to recommend a PI filter. The network across the top is 100nH + 3.1 ohms. 100nH is 10cm wire. You must include the series resistor to dampen.

Comment: More details on that PI filter: both caps(+PCB solder pads and traces) have parasitic L & R; Left cap has budget of 10nH + 20milliOhms. Right cap has budget of 5nH and 10milliOhms. If you examine the screen shot of Signal Chain Explorer, you'll see the ESR and ESL *above* each capacitor.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Thank you. Could you also add a full schematic with values so it is easily readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The intuitive way is to use an impedance nomograph. 
[image]

My simple conclusion is you dont have a handle on your specs yet.  What is your signal impedance, track impedance ( too inductive) and load Z? 
I use 10nH /cm and 100nH is way too much 10cm) for 2% track width, so you better couple the track to ground and get a distributed impedance or a good "transmission line" or a   "controlled Impedance".

> This assumes you have some understanding of Transmission Line theory with mismatched impedances for step response.

**It's hard to give a complete answer in 100 words or less , but your model is incomplete and you need to add larger and smaller caps to extend the bandwidth of power/gnd and lower the Z to match the DCR of the power plane which may be in x to xx mOhms. THen use 25 Ohm for ARM stripline/microstrip for clock signals.**

As it stands you can add 1 Ohm in series and get critical dampening, but then your load regulation is poor. So you need to move towards an ideal voltage source with low Z over the whole spectrum of noise e.g. down to x ns rise time for CMOS. with fBW=0.3/tR

But 1st you need to **memorize** the real equivalent circuit of all capacitors and inductors and the values of track inductance for a given width/length ratio ( e.g. 2%) per mm or per cm like **10nH/cm.**  There are lots of answers to this on this site which I and others have given.

Next you need to understand that %Overshoot or decay cycles of ringing is the inverse of Q where good speed and dampening is Q= 0.7~1 and Q=10 is bad like your signal with some unknown ESR in your model.

Next you need to understand that self resonant frequency ( sometimes called SRF ) *but more accurately called PRF for parallel resonant frequency and SRF is series resonant frequency.* (ignore this confusion  for now)

SRF can be a factor on any inductor, track or scope probe ground lead  due to inductance and conductor capacitance unless it is a well designed controlled transmission line with distributed RLC and matched load. ( or really short probe ground lead)

Next all cap. materials are different, where NPO ceramic and plastic film are about the best and ultra low electrolytics will have an ESR*C =T value < 10us while gen. purp. (G.P.) will be > 100us.

Lastly when doing a transient analysis examine the step load impedance ratio to source impedance. THis means if using a CMOS or MOSFET with an equivalent C and RdsOn value, compare that to your power/gnd track impedance and decoupling cap ESR and SRF (plots of Z vs f avail from many suppliers) and beware of complex interactive resonance. ( look for my answers with ref to Murata Caps)

I could write a book about this, so this is just to wet your appetite on how to analyze any RLC circuit in seconds.

- All inductors have DCR or ESR or series resistance and thus a ratio of T=L/R
- All capacitors have an ESR . read up on my relevant answers or a good book.

### most important for logic design

> - controlled impedance stripline and microstrip is your friend for high speed signal design.
> - Memorize the **(gap to gnd)/(track width) ratios** to ground for a rule of thumb like roughly 1:1 for near 50 Ohms with e=4 or whatever which is the RdsOn of most 5V CMOS and 25 Ohms (+/-25%) for 74ALVCxx and ARM chips. ( your rule of thumb may be slightly different....)

**- inductance factor is due to L/W ratio geometry only.**
   -  So a 1mm x 1mm cap has the same inductance as a 10cm x 10cm ground plane.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like this is a very complex problem... I think it would be best if I read a good book. Any recommendations?

Comment: What is your experience level?  For Z impedance of RLC  and stripline design? It is trivial to a pro designer and complex to the newbie without EE theory.  for ARM signals try to make signal tracks 25 to 50 Ohm tracks for textbook waveforms with controlled impedance

Comment: search for other answers {controlled impedance PCB } https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289516/clock-divider-ic-using-series-or-parallel-termination/289524#289524

Comment: As you can see 1 Ohm series R makes it a Q=1 or X(f) = R, but show where the problem is clearly and then which IC (ARM pin? Z=25? and track Z, and load RC? Your model is incomplete.